# 69kV insulator identification

Tags: electrical-engineering, transmission, insulator

Rather Specific question, is there a way or could anyone figure out what this clamp-top 69kV multipart insulator came from like who makes it or the technical name etc these are transmission lines in Alberta Canada.
[image: 69kV Multipart Lines by Altalink(formely transalta/calgary power ltd) Alberta Canada Credit:Tonyglen14 Flickr]

Comment: you asked a yes/no question

Comment: my guess is there's a part number on them

Comment: By comparing it to pictures of known insulators:
https://www.r-infinity.com/Books_Porcelain_Insulators.htm
Or by asking a collector from Alberta:
https://www.myinsulators.com/greatinsulators/